# Table hover issue

Tags: javascript, css

```
+----+----+----+-----+  
|    |    | c3 | c4  |  
|    | c2 +----+-----+  
|    |    | c5 | c6  |  
| c1 +----+----+-----+  
|    |    | c8 | c9  |  
|    | c7 +----+-----+
|    |    | c10| c11 |  
+----+----+----------+ 
+----+----+----+-----+  
|    |    | 3 | 4    |  
|    | 2  +----+-----+  
|    |    | 5 | 6    |  
| 1  +----+----+-----+  
|    |    | 8  |  9  |  
|    | 7  +----+-----+
|    |    | 10 |   11|  
+----+----+----------+
```

The above table has two rows and I want to highlight the row from  C1 to C11 using  hover and not to hover 1 to 11(ie: If i hover to first row(C1 to C11) the second row should not be highlighted and if i hover second row(1 to 11) first row should not be highlighted)

Comment: if you have a fiddle link post that or show ur code.

Comment: You named 'c3' twice. Are those tables inside tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

[image]

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/GJEwP/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">c1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">c2</td>
        <td>c3</td>
        <td>c4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c5</td>
        <td>c6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">c3</td>
        <td>c7</td>
        <td>c8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c9</td>
        <td>c10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}

tr:hover td{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming c4 is the fourth td of the first tr, you can do this

```
tr:first-of-type td:nth-of-type(4):hover{

}
```

assuming c1 is the first td of the first tr, you can use

```
tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type:hover{

}
```

if both my above assumptions are correct, and you want to set the same css for both, you can also combine it into,

```
tr:first-of-type td:nth-of-type(4):hover, tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type:hover{

}
```

Comment: here is a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uM8nu/) after using Mohsen's html structure and the css i had given just as a sample.